# How to Store List of selected value from multiselect dropdown list in array in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I used Bootstrap multiselect dropdown item, in which if I select many values it only select the first values, whats wrong in my code logic.

Asp dropdown list

```
<asp:dropdownlist  Width="320px" id="drplstGetDb" runat="server"  multiple="Multiple">  </asp:dropdownlist>
```

Javascript to enable multiple check feature from bootstrap.

```
$(function() {
    $('[id*=drplstGetDb]').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
```

C# Code to store in array.

```
int[] stopWordArray = new int[drplstGetDb.Items.Count];

foreach(ListItem listItem in drplstGetDb.Items) {
    if (listItem.Selected) {
        int i = 0;
        stopWordArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(drplstGetDb.Items[i].Value.ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

I am only getting first checked value in array, If I don't use this if if (listItem.Selected) I can Store all values in array. Can anyone suggest about this error,, Specially with Selected Logic. or Alternative to this..

Comment: Try to to get the id as an attribute with `[id*=drplstGetDb]` but instead use "#drplstGetDb" as it will get the id as an id and be more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are setting

```
int i = 0
```

inside the loop, you are setting the first array element of stopWordArray ALL THE TIME, no matter what. Move the

```
int i = 0
```

to the outside of the foreach and you should have better luck there.

Try this

```
int[] stopWordArray = new int[drplstGetDb.Items.Count];
int i = 0;
foreach(ListItem listItem in drplstGetDb.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected)
    {
        stopWordArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value.ToString()); //something like this
        i++;
    }
}
```

Maybe even easier would be to get rid of the int array and use a list

```
List<int> stopWordArray = new List<int>();

foreach (ListItem listItem in drplstGetDb.Items)
 {
     if (listItem.Selected)
      {
          stopWordArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listItem.Value.ToString()));
      }
 }
```

Comment: while debugging ,, for the first time value passed inside this condition,  if (listItem.Selected) but not from second time, even i had choosed many checkbox, i think there is problem in this  if (listItem.Selected) condition,